# ssl sockets not supported error

Tags: qt, websocket, tornado

I'm running tornado webserver for secure websocket connection on linux centos 6.6. I'm using Qt/c++ client to connect using a QWebsocket by opening a url like "wss://191.23.4.56/etr/job".
I'm getting error like,
"**SSL sockets are not supported in this platform**"
What is this error about?

Comment: Has anybody got similar error? My Qt client is running on Windos 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message *"SSL sockets are not supported in this platform"* is printed by `QWebSocket::open()` when the URL scheme is `wss` and `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` returns `false`.

The static member function [`QSslSocket::supportsSsl()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html#supportsSsl):

> Returns true if this platform supports SSL; otherwise, returns false.
>   If the platform doesn't support SSL, the socket will fail in the
>   connection phase.

That is your main problem. Now we need to find out why `Qt` thinks that SSL is not supported by the platform.

If you downloaded Qt as a binary package the function `supportsSsl()` tries to load required libraries `libssl` and `libcrypto` dynamically.

If those libraries cannot be loaded the function `supportsSsl()` returns `false`.

It is possible that `libssl` is not installed in your system. If you can find the library binaries in your system, but they are not loaded by Qt it possible that your binary `libssl` and/or `libcrypto` are not compatible with binary Qt.

To avoid such issues you can build your own Qt. For example, there is a fresh instruction how to build [Qt-5.5.1](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/qt5.html). Note the trick with the `-openssl-linked` configuration switch. It enables integration of OpenSSL libraries into Qt5 libraries instead of dynamic loading them at runtime.

Comment: Recently, the Qt Maintainance tool also supports installing the OpenSSL libraries. You still have to add their location to the PATH environment variable.
But, in my case, the dlls were not loading because of a missing dependency (msvcr100.dll), contained in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package. To find out what you are missing, use dependency viewer.