# Why is QsslSocket working with Qt 5.3 but not Qt 5.7 on Debian Stretch?

Tags: qt, ssl, debian

I have an app that uses the [QWebSocket class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html) but not SSL. It works fine when I execute a version compiled with Qt 5.3 but a Qt 5.7 executable freezes on the following warnings:

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve ERR_free_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup
QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_new_null
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_push
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_ex_new_index
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay_version
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
```

I am not seeing these warnings in the 5.3 version (that works properly), which suggests that I should not ignore them, [as asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361145/qsslsocket-error-when-ssl-is-not-used). Also, [`QT += network` is already in my src.pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846536/unresolved-functions-while-working-with-qsslsocket).

I was led to believe that [Debian dropped these symbols from the openssl package](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=797926). Could anyone tell me what's going on here and how I could fix this?

### System information

I'm running on Debian stretch

```
$ uname -r
4.8.0-2-amd64
```

I have openssl and libssl-dev installed

```
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.0c-2). 
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.0c-2).
```

I've tried running this with Qt 5.3 and 5.7

```
$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.7.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: I have the same issue and I am stuck with it... Still searching... Some more info about this:
* On my Debian Stretch, this issue happen on all Qt versions (Qt5.3, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8). It works for Qt5.3 for my colleague. So it might be due to the way Qt versions are installed, and not to Qt versions by themselves.
* It happens only for WebSocket clients, not WebSocket server.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Debian Stretch is shipped with OpenSSL 1.1; Qt uses OpenSSL 1.0; give Qt what it needs:

```
apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

---

**Detailed answer**

From this [answer about OpenSSL and Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480724/use-openssl-in-qt-c#39497754), I found a hint and I displayed SSL library version used for compile-time and run-time using:

```
qDebug()<<"SSL version use for build: "<<QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
qDebug()<<"SSL version use for run-time: "<<QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionNumber();
qDebug()<<QCoreApplication::libraryPaths();
```

And it displays:

```
SSL version use for build:  "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013"
... lot of SSL warnings...
SSL version use for run-time:  0
("/opt/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins", "/home/Project/..../build...Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_GCC_64bit-Release/src/release/build_linux_64")
```

But Debian Stretch is shipped with OpenSSL 1.1. As expected, all the threads on the Web about this issue are true: this is an OpenSSL library version compatibility issue.

I "apt install libssl1.0-dev" and the problem was solved. I still have 2 SSL warnings about SSLv3, but at least this is only warning (I read something on the Web about it, no way to find it again).

```
SSL version use for build:  "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013"
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
SSL version use for run-time:  268443839
("/opt/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/plugins", "/home/Project/..../build...Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_GCC_64bit-Release/src/release/build_linux_64")
```

**Summary**

Until Qt supports OpenSSL 1.1, you can either:

1. Install OpenSSL 1.0 (possible in Debian)
2. Compile OpenSSL 1.0 and install it (I did not test, but should work as 1.)
3. Ship OpenSSL 1.0 with your Qt application (I did not test, but should work as 1.)
4. Recompile Qt with "-openssl-linked" option (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141315/ssl-sockets-not-supported-error), I did not test and I do not want to)

Comment: Dear 7hibault, your comment should be the accepted answer, you saved my whole week! THANKS!

Comment: Those qDebug lines were the trick for me to figure out which version of OpenSSL my Qt was built with on Windows to resolve DLL Hell. Specifically, `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()` was the ticket.

Comment: Update : OpenSSL 1.1 is supported since Qt5.10 but you have to rebuild it with the appropriate configuration (see forum.qt.io/topic/103139/openssl-1-1-1-support/3). It is integrated by default since Qt 5.12.4 (https://blog.qt.io/blog/2019/06/17/qt-5-12-4-released-support-openssl-1-1-1/).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem on a debian stretch server. I fixed it with the help of 7hibaults comment.

Running the following command fixed the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Comment: I get following error on Ubuntu 16.04: E: Package 'libssl1.0-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: @KoviNET: I am too getting same error. In case you've resolved it, please can you share how did you resolve it

Answer (score 6):

For those who use **Ubuntu** `18.04+` you can use this built it works for newer versions also.

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was required to install older versions of Qt from their archive:
https://download.qt.io/new_archive/qt/
on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.  I needed to get Qt 5.5.1 and the .run file wouldn't run, until I installed this version of libssl1.0-dev

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy

Answer (score 3):

[Fylhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297296/8231908) does not work under Debian Buster as libssl1.0-dev was a transition package and is not supported anymore.

There is a bug report on Qt's Website and from [Giuseppe d'Angelo's comment](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68156?focusedCommentId=423468&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-423468) there are the following workarounds :

> **Workaround 1**
>
> If your distribution has a directory for OpenSSL 1.0 with the right
>   symlinks (e.g. Arch has /usr/lib/openssl-1.0/libssl.so) use
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH to force that directory to be searched first.
>
> **Workaround 2**
>
> Make your own directory with symlinks, and use LD_LIBRARY_PATH for
>   that.
>
> **Workaround 3**
>
> Rebuild your own Qt.

I could fix the problem using the second solution, commands detailed below in my case:

1. `mkdir openssl1.0 ; cd openssl1.0`
2. `cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2 libssl.so.1.0.2`
3. `ln -s libssl.so.1.0.2 libssl.so`
4. in QtCreator, Projects > Desktop Qt 5.8.0 > Build > Build Environment > Add : Variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, Value /path/to/dir/openssl1.0 (or add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/dir/openssl1.0"` before your command from the console)

You could need to do the same with libcrypto.so as well, but this was enough for me. This solution prevents you from changing the symlinks for the whole system.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Debian 11 (bullseye), and unable to install `libssl1.0-dev` then do the following:

Add the following two sources

```bash
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/source.list 
echo "deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/source.list
```

Then run `apt-get update`

and finally `apt install libssl1.0-dev`

Here's the [Source](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4764#issuecomment-527723675) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I have problem with Qt 5.11.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I got the ssl version used for Qt by running

```
qDebug()<<"SSL version use for build: "<<QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
```

Which print

`SSL version use for build:  "OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017"`

I resolved the problem by building `openssl-1.0.2k` got from here http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.0/postlfs/openssl.html.

Then run the command to build

```
./config --prefix=./usr --openssldir=./etc/ssl  --libdir=lib   shared   zlib-dynamic
make
```

After make successfully completed I got follwing library build in current directory

```
path/openssl-1.0.2k/libssl.so.1.0.0
path/openssl-1.0.2k/libssl.so
path/openssl-1.0.2k/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
path/openssl-1.0.2k/libcrypto.so
```

Then Open QtCreator, Projects > Desktop Qt 5.11.1 GCC 64bit > Build > Build Environment > Add : Variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with value `path/openssl-1.0.2k`.

In my case `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` already exist with some value so I edited it like `:/home/user/Qt5.11.1/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/lib::path/openssl-1.0.2k`

The above steps resolve the ssl warning problem with Qt5.11.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the following package with the following command in order to fix the problem:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change this symlinks in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` from:

`libcrypto.so` → `libcrypto.so.1.1`
`libssl.so` → `libssl.so.1.1`

to:

`libcrypto.so` → `libcrypto.so.1.0.2`
`libssl.so` → `libssl.so.1.0.2`

Comment: For what I know, changing a symlink in /usr/lib is not recommended. First the change will be done for your whole system (and some other components surely depend on libssl1.0.2 and does not support 1.1), and this will be automatically and hiddenly changed in case of update (security update to libssl1.0.3 for example).

Comment: Yes, but until today you have any options more

Comment: I disagree. There are at least the 4 options described in my answer. And this is not exhaustive.

Comment: the newer lib has a big list of functions removed/deprecated, so linking to it will not resolve anything, as when starting the application, those functions will still not be found!