# Can't open Mendeley Desktop on Debian Stretch QSslSocket errors

Tags: installation, mendeley, debian-stretch

I tried opening Mendeley through my terminal and got a bunch of errors and a pop-up window that says

> Mendeley Desktop is already running but may not be responding. Click
>   the Mendeley icon in the taskbar or dock to activate it.

But there's nothing in the taskbar/dock to click on. The terminal errors I get are:

```
$ mendeleydesktop
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve ERR_free_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_new_null
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_push
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_ex_new_index
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay_version
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_free_strings
```

I followed the advice from this post [Why is QsslSocket working with Qt 5.3 but not Qt 5.7 on Debian Stretch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094214/why-is-qsslsocket-working-with-qt-5-3-but-not-qt-5-7-on-debian-stretch) and now I have less errors

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libssl-doc linux-headers-4.9.0-4-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-4-common
  linux-image-4.9.0-4-amd64
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libssl-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,559 kB of archives.
After this operation, 407 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 libssl1.0-dev amd64 1.0.2l-2+deb9u2 [1,559 kB]
Fetched 1,559 kB in 2s (540 kB/s)          
(Reading database ... 433519 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.0f-3+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssl1.0-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 433434 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2l-2+deb9u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.0-dev:amd64 (1.0.2l-2+deb9u2) ...
Setting up libssl1.0-dev:amd64 (1.0.2l-2+deb9u2) ...

$ mendeleydesktop
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
```

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=131578 makes similar suggestions, along with making sure libcrypto.so and libssl.so are installed - but I can't work out how to install them? It seems like they should be a part of libssl1.0-dev which is now installed..?

Thanks for any advice :)